# How to create login page in google app engine using java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I would like to create my own login page instead of using the default one that is from google app engine. After the user click the login button, it will redirect them to the home page of my website. so is there a way to do so?

I am using java as programming language.

Would appreciate if anyone could help. Thanks.

Comment: I wish there was a simple way to add facebook as authentication method for your app but there isn't. You may want to have a look at a third-party system such as http://www.janrain.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this in App Engine is no different to doing it in any other Java servlet environment, except that you're storing your user data in the datastore. How exactly you implement it is up to you and depends on a number of factors; a complete tutorial on how to build a user authentication system seems out of scope for a stack overflow answer.

I'd strongly recommend using a prebuilt authentication solution, however; if you don't like Google User authenticaiton, App Engine comes with built in OpenID authentication as an option. Rolling your own makes you responsible for issues like secure password storage, which is hard to get right, exposes your users to potential security issues, and forces them to create yet another user account instead of using an existing one.